# Использование SSE инструкций в C++ коде (вычисление экспонент и логарифмов)

Tags: c++, ассемблер, математика, sse

Mожно ли использовать функции работы с SSE в с++ коде без включения ассемблерных ставок?

Особенно интересуют функции вычисления экспонент и логарифмов.

На сайте Intel в документации приводятся функции типа `_mm_exp_ps`. 
Но эта функция отсутствует в библиотеке `<immintrin.h>`.

Подскажите, как быть?

Comment: Большинство современных компиляторов вовсю генерируют инструкции SSE, если им это специально не запретить.

Comment: AnT - я смотрел дизасемблерный код, когда работаешь с float/double, то часто действительно идут SSE инструкции, но у меня цикл с кучей одинаковых расчётов (только разные параметры) и вот компилятор в Release не смог это обернуть в нормальный SSE, т.е. сделать нормальные векторные вычисления, вот я и хочу ему немного помочь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Встраиваемая функция `_mm_exp_ps` не является алиасом для ассемблерной инструкции, а является [частью библиотеки Short Vector Math Library (SVML)](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524316), распространяемой вместе с компиляторами Intel.

Comment: т.е. на VS компиляторе мне это недоступно? :(

Comment: @Zhihar именно так

Comment: жаль :( а как же мне используя VS2017 компилятор обратиться к SSE, который мой процессор поддерживает? Получается все нужные мне вкусности только через интеловский компилятор :(

Comment: @Zhihar, это не инструкция процессора, Вам же написали. Это библиотечная функция, для инструкций процессора должны быть intrinsics.